# Pointgrey camera driver parameter limits cfg file

Tags: ros, launch-file, binaries, build-from-source, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set the frame rate on my Point Grey Chameleon 3. The dynamic reconfigure has a max value of 100. This is set in the PointGrey.cfg file.  However, the camera itself is capable of higher frame rates.

I have installed the camera driver from apt:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-pointgrey-camera-driver
```

Is there a way for me to modify the PointGrey.cfg file somewhere? I assume with my install method that it is all packaged up in a binary file and not changeable. Is there a way to override the default PointGrey.cfg file with a custom one? Can I point the Nodelet at a new .cfg file? Maybe in the launch file?

I have a custom launch file already where I set various parameters for the Nodelet. I generated this launch file by copying the camera.launch file from the github page and adding parameters (https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/blob/master/pointgrey_camera_driver/launch/camera.launch). Is there a line I could add in here to tell the Nodelet to use a custom .cfg file?

I have tried installing from source so that I can modify the PointGrey.cfg file, but I have not had any luck getting that to work either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255151/pointgrey-camera-driver-parameter-limits-cfg-file/) by [eab](https://answers.ros.org/users/29425/eab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up figuring out how to install from source. I was trying to copy just the pointgrey_camera_driver subfolder, but you need to do the entire repository so that the dependencies are met.

After doing this, I was able to change the PointGrey.cfg file and get higher frame rates.

---

Originally posted by [eab](https://answers.ros.org/users/29425/eab/) with karma: 16 on 2017-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
If you feel you have answered your own question, then could you please accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of your answer? Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
As to the solution you ended up with: dynamic reconfigure is infrastructure that gets generated at compile time. So creating a workspace, cloning the sources, updating the config and then rebuilding is (at the moment) the only way to change the bounds for a config item.

**Comment by [eab](https://answers.ros.org/users/29425/eab/) on 2017-02-21**:
It says I need more "points" to accept or unaccept my own answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
I've just accepted it for you.